# Weak derivative of a multivariable function and Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

I have to check if the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y}$ is in the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$. I also have to check if it has a restriction to the boundary that is $L^2(\Gamma)$. Here $\Omega=(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

I almost have no idea how to answer the second question. For the first one, I tried to find if there was a weak derivative $g$ of $f$ such that $(f,\phi')=-(g,\phi)$ for $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. Here $(m,n)=\int_\Omega mndx$. To that end I had
\begin{align*}
(f,\phi')&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x+y}\phi'dxdy\\
&=\ldots=\\
&=-\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+y}}\phi dxdy\\
&=-(g,\phi)
\end{align*}

where I have used integration by parts and the fact that $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. Obviously I am extremely skeptical about my calculations here. How to show if $f(x,y)$ is/isn't in $H^1(\Omega)$? The other thing that came to my mind was to somehow use the first identity of Green. But then I am thinking $f$ would need to be in a vector field.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear what you mean by $\phi'$. You have to do the compuation for $\partial_x \phi$ and $\partial_y \phi$. But okay, the respective derivative of $f$ is the same anyway. Okay, we have established that the weak derivative wrt x and y is $-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+y}}$. Now, what does $H^1$ mean anyway? That $f \in L^2$ and the derivatives are in $L^2$. One might think that this might be problematic since $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$ does not convergence, but $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+y} dxdy$ is fine, check this.

The second question is about the boundary behavior. The trace theorem ensures the existence of a restriction in $L^2(\Gamma)$. You can also check that by hand. On the left hand side of the domain we have $x=0$ and $y \in (0,1)$. Then $\int_0^1 f(0,y)^2 dy=\int_0^1 y dy$ which is fine. You can check the other boundaries also.  (Actually, you do not know whether you are allowed to do this, since a function in $H^1$ might not be continuous. But here it is obvious)

Comment: how do you find the weak derivative wrt $x$ or $y$? do you just say since $f(x,y)$ is smooth, its weak derivative is the same as its classical derivative in the given domain?

Comment: One can argue about the regularity, yes. But you also did it correctly, computing $(f_x,\phi)=-(f,\phi_x)=-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) \partial_x \phi(x,y) dxdy$ and do integration by parts.